# Why are these Binary/RowVersion not match?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table like

```
                Thingy 
=======================================
| ... |        RowVersion     | ... |
=======================================
```

and another like

```
                Result 
=======================================
| ... |     ThingyRowVersion     | ... |
=======================================
```

In SQL Server the columns are of type `timestamp` and in C# they are of type `Binary`. What I'm seeing is a problem when I try to create a result with the same row version as a thingy, like

```
Result r = new Result()
{
    ThingyRowVersion = (from t in Context.Thingies where t.Id == id select t.RowVersion).Single()
}  
Context.InsertOnSubmit(r);
Context.SubmitChanges();
```

the row versions will not be equal right after the changes are submitted.

In C# land they appear to be equal right before I submit, but when I submit I see a mismatch like

`0x0000000000002787` / `0x0000000000002782`

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

A timestamp is automatically updated whenever a row is inserted or changed and isn't normally manipulated by the user. The most common operation with them is to use as a check when using optimistic concurrency to see if the row has been updated since the last time you read it. You may want to use something else like UniqueIdentifier to do what you want.